# How to insert spinner selected position value and EditText value together into SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am trying to add `spinner selected position` value and `edittext`  into `sqlite database` but I don't know how would I use Spinner position value during insertion into sqlite database.

Someone help me please.

Below is the spinner Item position code:

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Select expense type")) {
            // Do nothing

        } else {
            item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //Do nothing
 }
```

Below is the Code where I want to use Spinner Item Position selected value and edittext value togather for inserting into sqlite database. so how could I get spinner position value  for use into InsertExpense() function .

```
public void InsertExpense() {
       addExpId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a global variable to store the selected item in spinner

```
String selectedItem=";
```

and here

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //yourList is the array your are using in your spinner adapter
       selectedItem=yourList.get(position).toString();
    }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //Do nothing
 }
```

and then use this variable in your insertion method